# KineticJS move shapes between groups maintaining the position

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I'm using KineticJS and I'm adding some shapes into two groups.
I can drag and move the shape in the groups and after have to move the shape in another group.

When I move the shape from one group to another I lost the position of the shapes, they returns to its original position, the same that I had before I was moving in the other group.

Probably have to synchronize the the shape position in both groups, does KineticJS provide any features for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.

When a shape is moved from one group to another the x,y coordinates are unchanged.  This causes the shape to "jump" relative to its new group.

So if you move a shape to a new group:

```
circle1.moveTo(group2);
```

Then you must adjust the x,y of the shape to be relative to the new group:

```
circle1.x(circle1.x()-group2.x()+group1.x());
circle1.y(circle1.y()-group2.y()+group1.y());
```

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/e4vcM/